# SQL select display row data as columns for varchar items

Tags: sql, select, row

This is the query I am using to generate my table:

```
SELECT cu.idchanneluser AS Approver,
     mcr.idrule AS Rule,
     mrd.idseq AS Seq,
     mcr.idcust AS CustID,
     cu.iduser AS USERID
FROM mstchanneluser cu,
     mstcatruledetail mrd,
     mstcatrule mcr
WHERE idchannel='01'
     AND mrd.idlist=cu.iduser
     AND mrd.idrule=mcr.idrule
     AND mcr.nbrauth='2'
     AND mcr.isautoauth='N'
```

and this the snapshot of result:

[image]

but I want result like this:

```
   FirstAuthorizer SecondAuthorzier Rule    
   rohitcorp        ajitcorp         3090  
   CORPTEST         TESTCORP         8634
   ABHIMAKER        CORPTEST         11705
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN idseq = '0' THEN idchanneluser ELSE NULL END AS Approver,
    case when idseq = '1' THEN idchanneluser  ELSE NULL END AS secondApprover,
    cu.idchanneluser AS Approver,
    mcr.idrule AS Rule,
    mrd.idseq AS Seq,
    mcr.idcust AS CustID,
    cu.iduser AS USERID
FROM mstchanneluser cu, 
    mstcatruledetail mrd, 
    mstcatrule mcr 
WHERE idchannel='01'
    AND mrd.idlist=cu.iduser
    AND mrd.idrule=mcr.idrule 
    AND mcr.nbrauth='2'
    AND mcr.isautoauth='N'
```

and it will be returning me this result check the snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is derived from your second query, you just need to use `MAX` and group them by `mcr.idrule`

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN idseq = '0' THEN idchanneluser ELSE NULL END) AS Approver
    ,  MAX(CASE WHEN idseq = '1' THEN idchanneluser ELSE NULL END) AS secondApprover
    ,  mcr.idrule AS RULE
FROM   mstchanneluser cu
    ,  mstcatruledetail mrd
    ,  mstcatrule mcr
WHERE idchannel = '01'
    AND mrd.idlist = cu.iduser
    AND mrd.idrule = mcr.idrule
    AND mcr.nbrauth = '2'
    AND mcr.isautoauth = 'N'
GROUP BY mcr.idrule
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @kuya john it is started working for me.Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, by the way, what database server you are using?

Comment: Oracle database and as a client we are using PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

Another way in oracle with Analytical function lead lag

```
select tab.y FirstAuthorizer,tab.x SecondAuthorzier,tab.rule from
(
select lead(appprover,0) over (partition by rule order by seq) x ,
lag(appprover,1) over (partition by rule order by seq) y,
rule
from tbl ) tab
where tab.y is not null;
```